# Windows Store Apps: download website content for offline access in webview?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

is it possible to download a whole website content, save it in the App's local data folder, then load the website content in a webview so that the user can view it when offline ?

if so, would you please provide me with sample code or reference for APIs to achieve this

Comment: Is original website static or dynamic?

Comment: It's a dynamic website with many pages and lots of scripts

Answer (score 1):

download the entire website as a string

use 
`string testStr = await (new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");`

but apart from the html content. 
1 - The javascript references and the style sheet , the images all need to have a fully referenced path not relative path .
2 - this can be achieved only in Online mode if we have fully qualified path for the above.
3 - to show the images and javascript you need to have it in local storage or known folder or any other accesible folders like the library and all. 
4 - U need to append all javascript to the html in order to do `webview.NavigateToString(entire string)`.
5 - So the conceot is a bit too long . Please try following the steps if all resources are available else you wont be able to give it a shot

By resources I mean - Javascript, Images, Css files

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I implemented your approach, but as you said only the web page is downloaded, the CSS,images and scripts are missing, is there a method to download the whole website as we do from the browser ?

Comment: see the css are there with a kind of link href="../abcd.css" these might be relative paths . Once ou view source and click on the path it will take you to the css in the browser. but from app css can be detected as link tags. only thing if you get the relative path say "http://www.abcd.com/abc.css" then only you can download. In the entire website string you download you need to check for the css. this will really increase the task you want to do. And pretty huge task if you wanna hack into this .